# No matching client found for package name when building multiple flavours in Android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I know this has been asked a bunch of times on SO, I have tried answers from most if not all of SOs questions.
My problem is that I have an android app with two different flavours, a client one and a normal one, that way, therefore I had a product flavor for the client version setup like so in my build.gradle file:

```
   clientConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        applicationIdSuffix '.client'
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName '0.0.23'
        dimension 'cl'
    }
```

I then linked both apps to my firebase project and downloaded the google-services json file. The file is placed as follows:

[image]

But when I sync the gradle files, I get the following error:
[image]

What is it that Im doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you've done this, maybe you haven't. Do the applicationId in each of those google-services.json match the ones in firebase?

Comment: Yeah they match the ones in Firebase. Actually if you have two apps under one project google automatically generates the google-services.json file with the client ids for all the apps in a json array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by removing the google-services.json file and also removing it from the gradle, then I added it again after syncing using Firebase helper in Android Studio and it was able to build successfully

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you have already your answer by yourself, but I think your folder and your product flavor name have to be the same: here, you have *client* as your folder and *clientConfig* as your product flavor name. Change *clientConfig* by *client*